# Unpack error after running compilemessages in django

Tags: python, django, backend

I have a Django project, and it was working fine.
after some merges from my teammates, now when I try to run the server, AFTER using these `manage.py makemessages` and  `manage.py compilemessage` I get this error:

```
    magic = unpack('<I', buf[:4])[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: If I delete *.mo files and recompile messages, it works fine, BUT after another make&compile messages, the error returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem :

Sometimes when you do `./manage.py makemessages` , the .po files that you created, are being corrupted. They miss these lines :

```
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-05-09 11:28+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2019-02-12 14:59+0000\n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: en_US\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
```

Which leads to a bad .mo file.
And a bad .mo file causes the error.

**Solution:**

Delete all the .po files as well as .mo ones, and recreate them, or simply add these lines to the beggining of the .po file.